# Using std::max_element on a two dimensional matrix

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++

I have a two dimensional matrix

```
double TotalEnergy[200][47];
```

This matrix is populated with appropriate values. Now I am trying to find maximum value in each column.

How do I use `std::max_element` in this case?

Many thanks.

Best Regards

Chintan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert each individual column into a std::vector and use the std::max_element function on the vector. STL containers take care of all memory issues very efficiently without us having to worry about it.

```
double maxElements[47]; //This will contain the max of each column of TotalEnergy
std::vector<double> vec;
for(int k=0; k<47; k++)
{
  for(int l=0; l<200;l++)
    vec.push_back(TotalEnergy[l][k]);

  maxElements[k] = *std::max_element(vec.begin() , vec.end());
  vec.clear();
}
```

Comment: Thanks dude. I wanted a simple way but this works just fine. Cheers. Chintan

Answer (score 1):

According to [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/max_element) `std::max_elements` only works with iterators. Unless you want to create an iterator that walks every element of a 2D matrix, I suggest running `std::max_element` for every row (or column) of the matrix.

Example (untested) code:

```
double result{std::numeric_limits<double>::min()};
for(int iX{0}; iX < 200; ++iX) {
    result = std::max(result, std::max_element(std::begin(TotalEnergy[iX]), 
                                               std::end(TotalEnergy[iX])));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can make sure you are using pointers to first and last+1 elements:

```
double distBetweenNodes[N][N];
const double maxDist = *std::max_element(&distBetweenNodes[0][0], &distBetweenNodes[0][0]+N*N);
// Note that &distBetweenNodes[0][0]+P*N could be &distBetweenNodes[N][N]
```

Answer (score 0):

I just found that we can do this:

```
const int n = 555; // for example 

int arr[n][n];

// filling the array

int mx = *max_element(begin(arr[0]), end(arr[n-1]));
```